# Why typescript allows me to use number as index value for a string map?

Tags: typescript

I would expect this to be reported by typescript as an error:

```
const map: { [key: string]: string } = {};
const value = map[1]; // 1 is not a string...
```

Why typescript isn't complaining here?

Comment: Relevant [documentation about index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), see how a "number" index is treated like a subset of string.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz still looks pretty weird to me though.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the key of an object always be a string, if you pass a number it will automatically be converted to a string.

```
Let obj = {};
obj[3] = ‘something’;
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
// [‘3’]
```

If you use a map you can strict type the key values as

```
let m = new Map<string, any>();
m.set(3, "1st three");
m.set("3", "2nd three");
```